# Mapbox.js / Leaflet How to get properties of MultiPolyon on click?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm having some trouble trying to display the properties of a multipolygon feature when I click on it.

The feature belongs to a feature collection consisting of polygon features and MultiPolygon features.

The code can be viewed in a gist can be viewed at: http://bl.ocks.org/rustyb/fcd0b674a6d889a7529a

```
// load the geojson
counties.loadURL('cc.geojson')
  .on('ready', done); 

// log county name when feature clicked.
counties.on('click', function(e) {
        console.log(e.layer.feature.properties.NAME);
    });
```

Nothing fancy at all. However when I click on the MultiPolygon it does not return the properties of the feature.

Nor from looking at what is returned by leaflet does it return the feature as a `featureGroup` either.

Would really appreciate it if anyone had any advice on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet author here. What `e.layer` returns in this case is shape that is a part of the feature, not the feature itself (which would have the `feature` property).

This is fixed in the almost released Leaflet 1.0 beta 1, but for the current version, a workaround would be to put the click listener on each layer separately (e.g. iterating with `counties.eachLayer`), and rely on `e.target` instead of `e.layer`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That has indeed worked a treat for me. Will keep an eye out for when leaflet 1.0 goes steady.